# Is there anything besides groups that can describe symmetry?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

Thinking about the things in mathematics that can describe anything that isn't entirely random, I can only think of "groups". My reasoning being, that something that isn't random must have symmetry and so the symmetry can be described by a group. Even in physics the Universe is described by groups like O(3,1) and SU(3).

Even the integers are groups under addition or multiplication.

Is there some symmetric things in mathematics that no possible group can describe?

(Having written this, I'm thinking maybe rings or vertex algebras might be a candidate?)

Comment: Integers do not form a group under multiplication; ***invertible*** integers do, i.e. $\pm 1$. By the way, you may want to look at groupoids.

Comment: "Is there some symmetric things in mathematics that no possible group can describe?" No, not really. The symmetries of some object, at least by my personal intuition of what a symmetry ought to be, fulfills the group axioms. Another interesting question is, of course, the one in your title: are there things other than groups which may be used? Does a ring of symmetries make sense in specific cases, for instance?

Comment: Before asking this question, you should clarify for yourself and for us what you mean by "symmetry".

Answer (score 2):

In order to describe the symmetries of a group $G$ we have the group $Aut(G)$ of automorphisms of $G$ which actually comes with an inner automorphism morphism $\xi: G \to Aut(G)$ which sends $g\in G$ to the *inner automorphism* $h \mapsto g^{-1}hg$. This structure can be written $AUT(G)$; it  has the structure of *crossed module* which in general is a morphism $\mu: M \to P$ of groups such that $P$ operates on the right of $M$  and obeys the two rules: CM1)  $\mu (m^p)= p^{-1}\mu(m)p$, and CM2) $n^{-1}mn= m^{\mu(n)}$, for all $m,n \in M, p \in P$.  Crossed modules occur in discussing identities among relations for groups, and second relative homotopy groups $\delta:\pi_2(X,A,x) \to \pi_1(A,x)$. Then we can move to the automorphism structure $AUT(M \to P)$ of a crossed module!

Crossed modules also occur in the symmetry of directed graphs: see [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240499190068D) by John Shrimpton.

User lysiarus also mentions groupoids, for more on which see wikipedia.

Comment: Interesting. Never heard of crossed modules. So they would be a kind of meta-group then?

Comment: Actually the category of crossed modules is equivalent to a particular kind of _double groupoid_ . Groupoids also include transitions, not just symmetries. If $G$ is a groupoid, then the elements of $G(x,y)$, if they exist,  can be thought  of as _journeys_ from $x$ to $y$, or as _proofs_ that $x$  is equivalent to $y$.